# Using a dynamic variable as the name of a model

Tags: php, dynamic, laravel-5

How would I go about calling a model using a dynamic variable? I thought `$nameOfModel::all()` would work. I have 4 different tables that need to make use of the same function.

This is what a normal call looks like `tableOne::all()` so I'm trying to have something like:

```
$table = 'tableOne';
$table = 'tableTwo';
$table = 'tableThree';
$table = 'tableFour';

$contents = $table::all();
```

Comment: `${$nameOfModel}::all()`

Comment: Is there any documentation I can read on using ${}...I can't find anything after googling.

Comment: [Variables variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) , [Variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @pes502. Do you want to set this as an answer I can accept so you get some internet points? ;)

Comment: ok, I added it as an answer to this question. With accepted answer will be this question completed and solved :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use model name as a dynamic variable, you can easily achiev this with `${}` call.

For variable, which you mentioned it will be:

```
${$nameOfModel}::all()
```

You can also find more details about variable names (variables, functions, ...) in PHP doc:

[Variables variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

[Variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

Based on comments I think, that you need define your class as first, so your code must look like:

```
$table = 'tableOne';
$table = 'tableTwo';
$table = 'tableThree';
$table = 'tableFour';

$class = new $table;
$contents = $class::all();
```

Comment: Thanks pes502 but after reading the docs I don't think this will work. According to the docs if I use the example I added to my post, the call would come out as `$tableOne::all()` instead of `tableOne::all()`

Comment: @VenomRush and have you defined your class, before you cal `::all()` ? I added definition to my code.